# Programa para introducir caracteres entre cada letra de la cadena de texto

Tags: c, caracteres

estoy iniciando en C  y quisiera resolver este problema:

busco un programa para que introduzca un caracter cualquiera que se digite entre cada letra eje:
vacaciones

el resultado: v,a,c,a,c,i,o,n,e,s

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cual es problema?? y la pregunta no esta bien formulada Te invito a [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Lo que observo es que estas usando mal la funcion `strcpy`, le estas pasando un `char`, cuando el 2do parametro deberia recibir un `char*`.

Comment: hola, con lo que tengo en esta opción debería poder introducir hola y el resultado debe darme hola pero con un caracter entre cada letra

Comment: no entiendo que pretendes hacer. Te recomiendo editar la pregunta y aclarar el problema.

Answer (score 0):

puedes iterar a través de un ciclo `for`  por cada letra en `texto` e imprimir tu caractér(sic) despues

```
for(int i = 0; i!= strlen(texto); i++)
     printf("%c%c", texto[i], c);
```

o si lo quieres guardar en una variable puedes ocupar el malloc y free para lograr tu objetivo

```
/*El x2 es para poder insertar el caracter*/
size_t tamanio = sizeof(char)*strlen(texto)*2;
char *nueva_cadena = malloc(  tamanio );

nueva_cadena[tamanio-1] = '\0'

int indice = 0;
for(int i = 0; i <= strlen(texto); i++)
{

     nueva_cadena[indice] = texto[i];
     indice++;
     nueva_cadena[indice] = c;
     indice++;
     
}
```